# Addition between two column of two different table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Suppose I have two tables as `SEM1` & `SEM2`.

`Student_id` is common column between them. I have applied **left join between two columns** and I am adding students marks from both column.

If table `SEM1`  have record for particular student  having marks as `20`, but `SEM2` doesn't have record for that particular student then it should do addition as `20+0`.
**How to fire that query**?

Comment: use `SUM(`first_column` + IFNULL(`second_column`,0) )`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this the query will be

```
SELECT sum(s1.marks+s2.marks) AS total 
FROM sem1 AS s1 
LEFT JOIN sem2 AS s2 ON s2.student_id=s1.student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether record is available in next table or not using `IFNULL`, If no record is available then we will take it as '0'

```
SELECT sum(s1.marks+IFNULL(s2.marks,0)) AS total 
FROM sem1 s1 
LEFT JOIN sem2 s2 ON s2.student_id=s1.student_id;
```